# How to add manual text to header in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

This question probably stems from not being enough of an expert to actually be working on my own Magento store, but I am doing my best.

I would like to add a container of text directly above the search form in my Magento 2 header. I assumed this would be as easy as finding the file that contains the search block and inserting the div. Evidently, that's not how things work anymore.

Can you please advise me about the best way to do this? Basically, I would like to be able to have an area above the search bar where I can do callouts and promotional codes.

This should be simple...and it probably is. But I am lost.

Answer (score 2):

You can add manual text into header by set xml into **default.xml** file,

Create **default.xml** file into your `app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/layout` folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">   
      <body>  
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="customblock" before="top.search" template="Magento_Theme::custom.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>

    </body>
</page>
```

Create phtml file inside your templates folder,

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/themename/Magento_Theme/templates/custom.phtml
```

Now keep your static code or call static block inside template file,

```
<?php 
        //create block_identifier static block
        echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('block_identifier')->toHtml();?>

<?php echo __('This is test custom block.'); ?>
```

Clean cache and check inside header, New message are appear.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a static block in Magento admin panel so it can be edited later on if required, let's say the block id `custom_header_text`. Inside your `default.xml` file in custom theme `Magento_Theme/layout` folder add

```
        <referenceContainer name="header.wrapper">
          <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header.banner" after="logo">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">custom_header_text</argument>
            </arguments>
          </block>
        </referenceContainer>
```

This will place your custom block after logo that you can now position right using css and clear the `block-search` div so it sits underneath your banner.
[image]