# Magento 2.1.4 Add text next to search bar

Tags: magento2, search

[image]

I'd like to add some text as the screen shows, I'm into the form.mini.phtml file, but so far I've managed to place it up or down from the search bar, not on the left. Any ideas?

Comment: Please refer the link
(http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142189/how-to-add-manual-text-to-header-in-magento-2)