# Add customer service number at the left of the header

Tags: customer, header, add

I want to add customer service number on the left side of the header. How can I do it? There is no option in the back-end to add number.

Comment: Can you describe more or share you'r ScreenShot, which theme you are using?

Comment: I am using magento luma theme and I am a beginner. I don't know much about magneto. I am learning.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/142189/how-to-add-manual-text-to-header-in-magento-2

Have you try this?